# MySQL query to generate a user list who have at least one order but no order in this month till now

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table user and order. where foreign key in order table is user_id. I need the list of users who have at least one order but who don't order in this month till now.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the users whose last order was before the current month:

```
select u.user_id, u.username 
from user u
inner join order o 
on on.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.id, u.username
having max(o.OrderDate) < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: Thanks..its working after a little bit customization

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from users
where exists 
(
   select 1 from order
   where users.user_id = order.user_id 
   having count(*) > 1
) and not exists 
(
   select 1 from order 
   where DATE_FORMAT(order_Date, %Y%m) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y%m')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use aggregation:

```
select o.user_id
from orders o
group by o.user_id
having count(*) >= 2 and  -- at least two orders
       max(order_date) < curdate() + (1 - day(curdate())) day;
```

The expression `curdate() + (1 - day(curdate())) day` is a convenient way to get the first date of the month.